# Bert + Resnet joint learning, pytorch model is empty after instantiation

Tags: pytorch, resnet, bert-language-model, torchvision

I'm writing a simple joint model, which has two branches, one branch is a resnet50 another one is a `bert`. I concatenate the two outputs and pass that to a simple linear layer with 2 output neurons.

I implemented the following model :

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.nn as nn
from collections import OrderedDict
from transformers import BertModel

class BertResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BertResNet, self).__init__()
        # resnet
        resnet50 = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        n_inputs = resnet50.fc.in_features
        # compressed embedding space
        classifier = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
            ('fc1', nn.Linear(n_inputs, 512))
        ]))

        resnet50.fc = classifier # 512 out resnet 


        bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

        # final classification layer

        classification = nn.Linear(512 + 768, 2)
        #print(resnet50)
        #print(bert)

    def forward(self, img, text):
        res_emb = self.resnet50(img)
        bert_emb = self.bert(text)

        combined = torch.cat(res_emb,
                              bet_emb, dim=1)
        out = self.classification(combined)
        return out
```

But when I instantiate, I get an empty model:

```
bert_resnet = BertResNet()

print(bert_resnet)
```

Out:
`BertResNet()`

`list(bert_resnet.parameters())` also returns `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assigned the models to any attribute of the object of the `BertResNet` class. There are in temporary variables in the `__init__` method, but once that finishes, these variables are discarded. They should be assigned to `self`:

```py
def __init__(self):
    super(BertResNet, self).__init__()
    # resnet
    self.resnet50 = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
    n_inputs = self.resnet50.fc.in_features
    # compressed embedding space
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('fc1', nn.Linear(n_inputs, 512))
    ]))

    self.resnet50.fc = classifier # 512 out resnet 


    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

    # final classification layer

    self.classification = nn.Linear(512 + 768, 2)
```